# I want to perform the function in order

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, web, iframe

A.html

```
var iframe = document.querySelector('#test'); 
// iframe.src = 'B.html'

iframe.onload = window(){
   testFunction();
}
```

B.html

```
window.onload = window(){
   console.log('B.html');
}
```

I want "console.log('B.html') -> TestFunction(); "

but TestFunction(); is always executed first.(B.html onload is not working.)
help me...

Comment: Why not call `testFunction();` in `B.html`.

Comment: I want B.html onload first execute and A.html execute

Comment: How are these 2 files loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need your iframe to communicate with parent window somehow to signal that it's been loaded. Take a look at [cross-document messaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).
I can't put up a working snippet here because of cross-domain policies, but something like this should work if you have your own web server:

```
<iframe id='myFrame' src='B.html' onLoad='onFrameLoad()'></iframe>
```

---

```
// A.html
function receiveMessage(event) {
  console.log('A.html', event);
}
function onFrameLoad(){
  console.log('B.html');
  window.parent.postMessage('loaded');
}
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
```